# Laravel remove public route AND disable it for accessing

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I am using Laravel 7 within my last project. 
I used the same approach on all my Laravel projects to remove the 'public' from the route:
- create a .htaccess within the root folder and add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I agree, that this method is all around the google and also works locally. Everything perfect until here.

The problem is that I made a facebook ad campaign on this project which points to the homepage (/) of the website and also added a 'Book Now' button with a link to it. The strange thing is that the link from Facebook ad, points to **mywebsite.com/public** even I specified only **mywebsite.com** so I just tried to manual access that route with public, and it worked.

So looks like my website's homepage is / and /public/ in the same time.
I want to be accessible only on / and disable the 'public'. Maybe if it's still specified, to be redirected to /.
I also read about that kind of fix to rename 'server.php' to 'index.php' and copy the .htaccess from public to the root, but there are a lot of negative advices not to do this for security reasons.

What would be the proper and also secure way to achive this ?

Comment: the root directory needs to be set to `var/www/somewebsite/public` (or whichever location). If youve done that correctly, you shouldnt have to mention `public` in your `/public/.htaccess` file. You can basically use the default Laravel .htaccess

Comment: also `server.php` (which should be one level higher, in your project root directory) should not be used to run a production level server.

Comment: I didn't make any change to /public/.htaccess, that's the Laravel default one. I`ve changed(created) only the .htaccess from the public_html directory (parent directory of public) only. The website's homepage works with and without 'public' in url, but I want only '/' to respond, and '/public/' to be redirected to '/' . There should be a way to do this using .htaccess

Comment: the `public_html` dir is afaik a synonym for the `public` dir. Your site should not have any `/public/` url that redirects to `/`. The main reason to set your public dir up properly is that it will result in only 1 entry point for your app, being `index.php`.

Comment: ok.. I see.. I think you mean to move the entire laravel folder to the parent one, then move the public files to public_html, then change the index.php correct path. I used this solution few yers ago.. but I thought I can do this with .htaccess . Anyway.. thanks for the hint. Appreciate your help

Comment: yes moving it up 1 directory sounds about right